# Does GLIFFY diagram maker supports DFD?

Tags: jira, dataflow-diagram, dfd, gliffy

I am using Gliffy tool integrated with Jira and wanted to design data flow diagram but unable to find one. Is that available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gliffy does not seem to have specific data-flow diagrams.

In their own documentation they explain that DFD’s can be produced using [flow-chart diagramming](https://www.gliffy.com/blog/what-is-a-data-flow-diagram).  The example they give uses the Gane & Sarson notation. For Yourdon/DeMarco you may use the circle in the flowchart symbols instead of the rounded boxes.

This being said, this tool limitation may be the opportunity to transition to the more powerful and precise [UML activity diagrams](https://www.gliffy.com/resources/how-make-activity-diagram-uml), which allow to mix control flow and object flow semantic. Despite the different symbols, it can express everything that a DFD diagram can represent and more.